# Cut string from end to specific char in php

Tags: php, string

I would like to know how I can cut a `string` in PHP starting from the last character -> to a specific character. Lets say I have  following link:

```
www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834
```

and I want to get `2535834`

Important note: the number can have a different length, which is why I want to cut out to the `/` no matter how many numbers there are.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case, an url, use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) :

```
echo basename('www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834');
```

---

A more general solution would be `preg_replace()`, like this:

```
                       <----- the delimiter which separates the search string from the remaining part of the string
echo preg_replace('#.*/#', '', $url);
```

The pattern '#.*/#' makes usage of the default greediness of the PCRE regex engine - meaning it will match as many chars as possible and will therefore consume `/abc/123/xyz/` instead of just `/abc/` when matching the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, thats simple. Btw, use `dirname()` if you want to obtain the other part of the string, meaning the path instead of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) AND [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
<?php
$str = 'www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834';
$tmp = explode('/', $str);
echo end ($tmp);
?>
```

[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/x3nKXcCy)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(So you can get the number with or without a slash, if you need that)

```
<?php

    $url = "www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834";
    preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => /2535834 [1] => 2535834 )
```

Answer (score 0):

With [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in action

```
$str = 'www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834';
echo str_replace("otherurl/", "", strstr($str, "otherurl/"));
```

`strstr()` finds everything (including the needle) after the needle and the needle gets replaced by "" using `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

if your pattern is fixed you can always do:

```
$str = 'www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834';
$tmp = explode('/', $str);
echo $temp[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine version:

```
$string = "www.whatever.com/url/otherurl/2535834";
echo substr($string, strrpos($string, "/") + 1, strlen($string));
```